# Find out encoding directly from an input stream

Tags: java, inputstream

Lets say I set up an input stream, how would I be able to figure out what the encoding is directly from the stream of data itself? Do I just make assumptions or is there a way to know for sure what the encoding is?

EDIT: While reading the file, like if I were to build my own inputStream reader.

Comment: I just added an edit. If I were to build an inputStream reader from scratch, how would I figure out the encoding.

Comment: In the general case, you cannot determine the encoding from the encoded data alone.  There are reasonably good (and fairly complex) algorithms for trying to *guess* from a long enough input, but the only ways to *know*  are (1) to be told out-of-band, or (2) for it to be expressed literally in the stream itself.  In the latter case, a certain amount of trial and error may still be required.

Comment: What kind of file? *Any* file?

Comment: Yes any file, I'm mostly just trying to get a better understanding of how streams and encoding work.